# Apache Spark distributed sql

Tags: apache-spark, design-patterns, apache-spark-sql

I use Spark DataFrameReader to perform sql query from database. For each query performed the SparkSession is required. What I would like to do is: for each of JavaPairRDDs perform map, which would invoke sql query with parameters from this RDD. This means that I need to pass SparkSession in each lambda, which seems to be bad design. What is common approach in such problems?

It could look like:

```
roots.map(r -> DBLoader.getData(sparkSession, r._1));
```

How I load data now:

```
JavaRDD<Row> javaRDD = sparkSession.read().format("jdbc")
            .options(options)
            .load()
            .javaRDD();
```

Comment: roots.map(r -> DBLoader.getData(sparkSession, r._1)); is not the right approach. in general,   you will not need to pass session into lambda.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of Big Data is to have data locality and be able to execute your code where your data resides, it is ok to do a big load of a table into memory or local disk (cache/persist), but continuous remote jdbc queries will defeat the purpose.